# Imagemagic gives me error while uploading a .txt or a .html file, whereas i can successfull upload a image(.png, .jpeg)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick

Imagemagic gives me error while uploading a `.txt` or a `.html` file, whereas I can successfully upload a image(`.png`, `.jpeg`)

Error: Project files files

```
Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError
```

Model Code:

```
class ProjectFile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  has_attached_file :files, :styles => {:medium=>"300x300>",:thumb=>"100x100>"},
                            :storage => :s3,
                            :s3_credentials => File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'aws.yml'), 
                            :path => ":class/:attachment/:id/:style.:extension"
end
```

Can anyone help me out with error.

Answer (score 1):

Paperclip can't calculate size (geometry) of not image files (see it [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/geometry_detector_factory.rb#L10)) and raise exception.

In you case you should specify content type filter as described [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#validations) to allow uploading of image files only.

Comment: Hey maxd, as you suggested i added content_type and size attributes:
Adding this to model, dosent work:




validates :files, :attachment_content_type => { :content_type => ['image/png', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/gif', 'application/pdf'], :size => { :in => 0..1.megabytes } }

Still the same error :(

Comment: Are you uploading PDF file?

Answer (score 1):

Hey I resolved the issue, I was uploading a .txt and .pdf file and i had specified styles attribute while uploading the file.
Following is code:

class ProjectFile < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :project

has_attached_file :files,

```
                           :storage => :s3,

                           :s3_credentials => File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'aws.yml'),
                           :path => ":class/:attachment/:id/:style.:extension"
```

end

Removing style attribute resolved my problem. :)